# Where can I add form control in my html when loading a registration form and iterating over that form?

Tags: html, django, django-forms

So I'm loading my registration form into my html and then using a for loop to iterate over those fields. I am wondering where I can add form control to show a green box around my username field so that a user knows if a username is taken before hitting the submit button. I tried adding it to the form tag and setting a div tag around `{{field}}` but neither of those work. Furthermore, how can I make it ONLY for Username?

**registration.html**

```
    {% block content %}
<br>
<h1 class="text-center"  style="color:#f5387ae6">Register to fall in love today!</h1>

    <form method="post" style="width:700px;margin:auto" action="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class= "form" >


        {% bootstrap_form registration_form%}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in bootstrap_form %}


            <p>
                <div class="form-control is-valid">
                    {{field.label_tag}}
                    {{field}}
                </div>
                {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small style="color:grey;">{{field.help_text}}</small>

                {% endif %}

                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red;">{{error}}"</p>
                {% endfor %}

            </p>


        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" id="accept-terms" class="form-check-input">
            <label for="accept-terms" class="form-check-label">Accept Terms &amp; Conditions</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

**reg_form**

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):


class Meta:
    model = Profile 
    fields = ("username","email","description","photo","password1","password2")
```

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class Conversation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class UserVote(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))






class InstantMessage(models.Model):


    sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'receiver',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data creation",default=timezone.now, null=False)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message

    #tests to see if messages are exclusive between sender, receiver (won't work with new model)
    @classmethod
    def find_messages_exclusive_to_profile(cls,sender,receiver):
        #members = receiver AND sender, not receiver or sender 
        exclusive_conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members= receiver ).filter(members= sender)


        exclusive_messages = InstantMessage.objects.filter(conversation__in=exclusive_conversations)

        return exclusive_messages
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a view which, given a string can check to see if that object exists in the database:

```py
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import JsonResponse

def check_if_username_exists_view(request, username):
    name_taken = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
    data = {
        'name_taken ': name_taken
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Then within your login page you will need some javascript similar to the below:

```js
$("#username").change(function(val){
    $.get( {% url 'user_exists_view' %} + val, function( data ) {
      alert( "username taken: " data.name_taken );
    });
})
```

Comment: Ok, can you actually plug it in and give me the answer? I went ahead and added my models.py. I am totally new to JS and do not understand where and how to plug this into my code. Your answer would help me understand it.